# Naming conflict: Same method name in inherited class and interface

Tags: actionscript-3, conflict, naming

```
public class A extends B implements C {
}
```

Class B and interface C have the same member function name（not the same signature）.
This code can't be compiled. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inherited class implements your interface method, so there should not be an error.  In fact, both having the same name is really the idea of implementing an interface...

Here's a check list:

- The method must have not only the same name, but the same signature. Make sure you've specified the correct argument and return types (this includes initial values).
- If your sub class A also implements the same method, you must mark it as `override`. Same rules apply regarding the signature.
- If you do override B's method, it must not be declared `final`.

Comment: yes, the method have the same name, but don't have the same signature.

Comment: Then that's how you fix your problem :)

Comment: Then you can't extend B and implement C.  How about favoring composition over inheritance and making B a member of A?

Answer (score 0):

If your class does not have the exact same method name AND signature, it is not properly implementing your interface. That's the long and short of it. You can either remove the implementation or change the method signature to fix it.